# How to escape % in String.Format?

Tags: java, android, string, syntax

I am storing a SQL query in my strings.xml file and I want to use `String.Format` to build the final string in code.  The `SELECT` statement uses a like, something like this:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM mytable WHERE Field1 LIKE '%something%'
```

In order to format that I replace 'something' with %1$s so it becomes:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM mytable WHERE Field1 LIKE \'%%1$s%\'
```

I escape the single quotes with the backslash.  However I am not able to escape the % sign.

How can I include a like statement in my strings.xml file?

Comment: Don't forget to escape the %s properly.

Comment: [SQL injection alert](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html). [Prepare yourself](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: They'd be injecting into their own database, no concern here ;)

Comment: Well, even if it is Your own database, it is possible to accidentally write queries that do bad things. Or just write queries that do not compile. Preparing queries is a good habit to get into.

Comment: Although it's slower than `String.format()` you might consider using `MessageFormat()` instead.

Answer (score 1187, accepted):

To escape `%`, you will need to double it up: `%%`.

Answer (score 28):

To complement the previous stated solution, use:

```
str = str.replace("%", "%%");
```

Comment: This will replace % that are already doubled. Please read the other answer.

Comment: @Toilal Why would anyone escape something that is already escaped? And if he would, why not actually do it? Maybe he intended to have two % signs, so the correct escaped form would be '%%%%'

Answer (score 5):

This is a stronger regex replace that won't replace %% that are already doubled in the input.

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?:[^%]|\\A)%(?:[^%]|\\z)", "%%");
```

Comment: seems to be an error with the regex:

"76%".replaceAll("(?:[^%]|\\A)%(?:[^%]|\\z)", "%%")

gives

"7%%"