# java 1.8: String#format eating characters when called without format params

Tags: java, string, format

In my production code I noticed that the method `java.lang.String#format` "eats" the first character of the String to be formatted when used without specifying the formatting parameters.

Thus

```
String.format("%%myStringValue\r\n");
```

produces the following console output:
    `%myStringValue`

See, how one of the percent characters gets away? Why is it so? I couldn't find any hints on that in the docblock of the method.

Comment: As described in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) under "Conversions", `%%` is converted to `%`.

Comment: It works as it is supposed to work. Since `%` is a special character in a format string, you need to escape it with `%%` to get a single percent sign in the output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape % in String.Format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011932/how-to-escape-in-string-format)

Comment: Yes, that is the correct behaviour when using the escape character.

Comment: Oh my god... My apologies, I had a "blackout". I used this thing so many times while specifying exception messages. for example. The double `%` chars confused me a bit. Thank you all for the quick responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence %% is an *'escape sequence'* to be able to print the % char itself, which otherwise would be interpreted as [format specifier](https://sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/specification.htm)