# String.format launch MissingFormatArgumentException due two "%" in text

Tags: java, string

I have a text like:

```
DISK_ERROR_MESSAGE = "Server %s is using more than 90% of the disk."
```

The problem, is when I try to do something like:

```
String.format(DISK_ERROR_MESSAGE,host.getName())
```

Java launches the error:

```
Method threw 'java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException' exception.
java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '% o'
```

The problem is that % of the 90%.

But I don't know how to avoid it without separating the text in two strings.

Comment: Ok, didn't found this answer... for me is ok to close it. Sorry!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To escape `%`, you will need to double it up: `%%`.

So, you need to change your string to

```
DISK_ERROR_MESSAGE = "Server %s is using more than 90%% of the disk."
```

Comment: This is a literal copy-paste of answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5011981/5771446

Comment: Yes.  I know. Just checking downvotes. Yesterday I had a discussion over it with a senior member. They are saying that we should answer duplicate questions.

Comment: What? Is there a meta discussion on this?

Comment: Yes :)
There are so called _seniors_ who got reputation bu asking duplicate questions and duplicate answer.

Comment: I cannot delete this answer, as it is accepted :(