# JAVA JSP wrong behavior in textbox with special characters like %

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts

when i insert "%165%" in a textbox, the server recept "a5%". Why happend that? is a hexadecimal conversion...why? 
In my ajax script, i use encodeURIComponent(), and the result, before send the post is fine:

"numero=%165%" --> "numero=%25165%25"

Its not a error, is a wrong behavior, because the server recept "a5%" and not "%165%"
I need help please...thanks so much!
JAVA, strut1

SOLVED: A class named XSSFilter.java was the problem in the web.xml file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011932/how-to-escape-in-string-format

Comment: What is the error? Would you mind to post that in your question, please?

Comment: done! is a wrong behavior....not a error....thanks