# String decimal to percentage in java

Tags: java, math, percentage

I have a string value as below:

```
String percValue = "0.0209"
```

How can I convert this to something like as below

```
String formatedValue = "2.09%";
```

Can someone help me what is the simple and best way to convert this?

Comment: First you'll want to convert `percValue` to a `Double`, multiple it by 100, and then you can use something like `String.format()` to ensure that the resulting value only shows 2 decimal places. You can read more about string formatting here: https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape % in String.Format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011932/how-to-escape-in-string-format)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One good way would be to:

- convert your percentage string to a number (needs to be a `double` type variable, so it can hold the decimal places...),
- multiply the value by 100 to make it a percentage,
- re-format the number in a string.

```java
String percValue = "0.0209";
double percentage = Double.parseDouble(percValue) * 100;
String formattedValue = String.format("%.2f%%", percentage);
```

Explanation:

- `Double.parseDouble()` takes your string as a parameter and returns a double value which you can do things like multiplication and addition with, and
- `String.format()` lets you precisely control how your number is converted back to a String!
- "%.2f" means "Take the next argument which is a floating-point variable and put it here, with two decimal places".
- "%%" means "print a single '%'". You need two to "escape" it, since percent symbols are not literally interpreted in format strings.

Answer (score 1):

You should parse the `String` into a `double`, multiply by 100, and then append the `%` sign to it as follows:

```
String percValue = "0.0209";
double per = Double.parseDouble(percValue);
String percentage = (per*100)+"%";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your string value and then multiply by 100, something like this:

```
 String percValue = "0.0209";
 double value = ( Double.parseDouble(percValue)) * 100;
 String formatedValue = value + "%";
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert String to BigDecimal(for Big numbers) and multiply by 100.

```
String percValue = "0.0209";
BigDecimal temp=new BigDecimal(percValue).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)).stripTrailingZeros();

String formatedValue =temp.toString() + "%";
```