# What does this mean "xmlns:xliff"? XML

Tags: android, xml, syntax, xliff

What does this mean?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
```

It can be seen in `Strings.xml` as part of the resources folder `values` in Android projects.

Comment: While these answers address the xliff tool without specific reference to Android, I have a more Android-specific answer on a related question --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/50233090/383414

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is xml namespace used for xliff. Xliff is used for localization purposes. You can read more about xliff [here](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/xliff/faq.php).

Comment: what the meaning of this

`<string name="format_full_friendly_date"><xliff:g id="day">%1$s</xliff:g>, <xliff:g id="date">%2$s</xliff:g></string>`

Comment: @BasheerAL-MOMANI: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656371/dynamic-string-using-string-xml

Answer (score 7):

XLIFF is the [OASIS XML Localisation Interchange File Format](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/xliff/faq.php).

`xmlns:xliff` is an XML attribute name. The `:xliff` indicates we are using the `xliff` namespace.

`urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2` identifies the schema location; the choice of format is at the discretion of Oasis, I'd assume it has meaning.

Comment: Is it necessary to have the `xliff` in an xml file?

Comment: No, it is not necessary if you don't use `XLIFF`. And you most likely don't (if you would, you'd knew what it was :).

Answer (score 0):

In the `xmlns:xliff` , **xmlns** mean **XML namespace**. That provide unique identification to elements and attributes in an XML document.

**xliff** means **XML Localization Interchange File Format**.

The `xmlns:xliff` specifies the namespace use in XLIFF Version 1.2, 2.0 and 2.1. Those XLIFF files use for the localization(language translation) purposes in most applications.
There are several declared XML names

- urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:2.0
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:matches:2.0
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:glossary:2.0
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:fs:2.0
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:metadata:2.0
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:resourcedata:2.0
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:changetracking:2.0
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:sizerestriction:2.0
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:validation:2.0

The first namespace `urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:2.0` corresponds to the namespace of core subset of XLIFF 2.0. And any XML document that declares the namespace `urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:2.0` as its main namespace has  as the root element and complies with the XML Schemas and the declared Constraints that are part of this specification.

Can read more about namespaces and xliff [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/xliff-core/v2.0/os/xliff-core-v2.0-os.html).