# Cannot find declaration

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I upgraded to Android Studio V3. On one of my projects (not all) I am getting this;

```
<resources xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
```

This is in values.xml (a system therefore uneditable file) and is giving me

> Cannot find the declaration of element 'resources'

This is an error that is preventing my project from building. Any ideas on what I can do to remove xliff?

Comment: Looks like you can delete it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158157/what-does-this-mean-xmlnsxliff-xml for details.

Comment: That just tells me about xliff. It does not tell me how to get rid of the error.

Comment: Just remove the namespace declaration form the `<resources>` element?

Comment: It is under the build folder which is generated and cannot be edited. If I remove it, studio just puts it back in when it does a rebuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was not with the resources tag but with a nested item tag. The item tag was set by a colour item in the styles.xml. I removed the item tags from the styles xml and the project built. This was after messing around with the theme editor for a couple of hours.