# Concatenate 2 strings in android?

Tags: java, android, string-concatenation, string-formatting

I am displaying a Error message in a Toast with `strings.xml`.

Like this
`mErrorMsgId=R.string.username_or_password_incorrectfull;`

But now i need to concatenate the message with `R.string.add_selfhosted_blog` to avoid translation inconsistencies.

Read some similar questions but can't figure it out.

**EDIT:**

I want to concatenate nux_add_selfhosted_blog after the word tap in the username_or_password_incorrectfull string ...

```
<string name="username_or_password_incorrectfull">The username or password you entered is incorrect
 \- If you\'re a self hosted user, don\'t forget to tap **Add Self Hosted Site** and fill the URL field</string>
```

`<string name="nux_add_selfhosted_blog">Add self-hosted site</string>`

How can i acheive this ??

Comment: Show us more code to help you better, string concatenation is actually a very simple thing to do

Comment: Pls Read the EDIT ...

Answer (score 5):

You cannout concatenate `R.string.username_or_password_incorrectfull` with `R.string.add_selfhosted_blog` directly as they are not `String` instances as such but rather the resource id to the actual String in the `strings.xml`. You can get the 2 strings and then concatenate them normally.

Something like this:

```
String string1 = getResources().getString(R.string.username_or_password_incorrectfull);
String string2 = getResources().getString(R.string.add_selfhosted_blog);

String combined = string1 + string2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Second parameter of method makeText accepts stringResId or just String

For example:

```
String error = getResources().getString(R.string.username_or_password_incorrectful);
String error2 = getResources().getString(R.string.add_selfhosted_blog);
String conctString = error + " " + error2;
Toast.makeText(context, conctString, duration).show();
```

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656371/dynamic-string-using-string-xml

Answer (score 1):

you can use MessageFormat.

set username_or_password_incorrectfull as the format string

... forget to tap {0} and fill the URL...

then use MessageFormat.format(username_or_password_incorrectfull, nux_add_selfhosted_blog)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply concate those two `String` from `strings.xml` resource then you can achieve by this...

```
String errorMessage = getString(R.string.username_or_password_incorrectfull) + getString(R.string.add_selfhosted_blog);
```

Then show the concated error message in the `Toast

```
Toast.makeText(context, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: `mErrorMsgId` must be int type in op question.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a string in Middle of another string in following way,

```
String mErrorMsgId = getResources().getString(R.string.username_or_password_incorrectfull); // +  getResources().getString(R.string.nux_add_selfhosted_blog);

String firstPart = mErrorMsgId.substring( 0, mErrorMsgId.indexOf( "tap") + 4 );
String selfhosted_blog = getResources().getString(R.string.nux_add_selfhosted_blog) + " ";
String thirdPart = mErrorMsgId.substring( mErrorMsgId.indexOf( "tap") + 4 );
mErrorMsgId = firstPart + selfhosted_blog + thirdPart;
```

Comment: Well I added the strings you have given in your question and it is showing me proper output, Are you getting any error ?

Comment: your code just concatenates both the strings.But i need to concatenate in the middle of a string

Comment: Do you mean after this text `forget to tap` ?

Comment: Its not possible, I ran the code in my eclipse, and in it showing proper result.

Answer (score 0):

Just retrieve string from both id's and concate with `+` as ususal and put resulted string variable in Toast.

```
String messageToUser = getResources().getString(R.string.username_or_password_incorrectfull) +  getResources().getString(R.string.add_selfhosted_blog);
Toast.makeText(context, messageToUser, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using this library I've created: https://github.com/LikeTheSalad/android-stem it will concatenate all of you strings you want to based on a template string you define, and then it generates a final XML string at build time. So for your case, you can define your strings like so:

```
<string name="nux_add_selfhosted_blog">Add self-hosted site</string>
<string name="username_or_password_incorrectfull">The username or password you entered is incorrect
 \- If you\'re a self hosted user, don\'t forget to tap ${nux_add_selfhosted_blog} and fill the URL field</string>
```

And then after building your project, the following string will be generated:

```
<!-- Auto generated during compilation -->
<string name="username_or_password_incorrectfull">The username or password you entered is incorrect
     \- If you\'re a self hosted user, don\'t forget to tap Add self-hosted site and fill the URL field</string>
```

The tool will keep this auto-generated string updated for any changes you make to the template and or the values. More info on the repo's page.

Answer (score 0):

**You can simply add/concatenate string as you do in C#/Java,**

*Here Address1 and Address2 are EditText(TextBox)*

```
String finalString = Address1.getText().toString() + " "+ Address2.getText().toString();
```