# Error in concatenating two strings?

Tags: java, android, string

I am trying to concatenate two strings like the below Method.I Referred from [dynamic String using String.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656371/dynamic-string-using-string-xml)

```
String incorrect = getResources().getString(R.string.username_or_password_incorrect);
mErrorMsgId = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.username_or_password_incorrectfull), incorrect);
```

it returns
`error: incompatible types required: int found: String`

**EDIT**

I need to replace the %1$s in the below string with this string R.string.username_or_password_incorrect

```
'<string name="username_or_password_incorrectfull">The username or password you entered is incorrect \- If you\'re a self hosted WordPress.org user, don\'t forget to tap %1$s and fill the URL field</string>'
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: is `mErrorMsgId ` an int field?

Comment: You are using String.format for concatenate?

Comment: @Dan private int mErrorMsgId;

Comment: What are you trying to use the 2 string for? format them to what? It seems you have the whole concept wrong, if you'd tell us what you are trying to achieve, we might be able to direct you to your answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible. If it is, I'm not aware of it.

What you could do, is something like this;
Create 2 string, one that contains `The username or password you entered is incorrect \- If you\'re a self hosted WordPress.org user, don\'t forget to tap` and another one with `and fill the URL field`

and then contcatenate it with the 'incorrect' variable.

```
String a = getResources().getString(R.string.username_or_password_incorrectfull);
String b = getResources().getString(R.string.username_or_password_incorrectfull2);
String mErrorMsgId = a + incorrect + b;
```

Note: A better approch would be to use the `StringBuilder` class to concatenate different variables types, but for the sake of example, this should do.

Answer (score 0):

This is very confusing, why would have `mErrorMsgId` as an int? change this to a `String` and it won't error anymore:

so change

```
private int mErrorMsgId;
```

to

```
private String mErrorMsgId;
```