# Android TextView : "Do not concatenate text displayed with setText"

Tags: android, concatenation, textview, string-concatenation

I am setting text using **setText()** by following way.

```
prodNameView.setText("" + name);

prodOriginalPriceView.setText("" + String.format(getString(R.string.string_product_rate_with_ruppe_sign), "" + new BigDecimal(price).setScale(2, RoundingMode.UP)));
```

In that **First** one is simple use and **Second** one is setting text with formatting text.

Android Studio is so much interesting, I used Menu **`Analyze -> Code Cleanup`** and i got suggestion on above two lines like.

[image]

> Do not concatenate text displayed with setText. Use resource string
>   with placeholders. less... (Ctrl+F1)
>
> When calling **TextView#setText:**
>
> - Never call Number#toString() to format numbers; it will not handle fraction separators and locale-specific digits properly. Consider
>     using String#format with proper format specifications (%d or %f)
>     instead.
> - Do not pass a string literal (e.g. "Hello") to display text. Hardcoded text can not be properly translated to other languages.
>     Consider using Android resource strings instead.
> - Do not build messages by concatenating text chunks. Such messages can not be properly translated.

What I can do for this? Anyone can help explain what the thing is and what should I do?

Comment: That means you should pass only a `String` into `setText()`. Ex: `setText(name)` in stead of `setText("" + name)`. Because if you concatenate text, it will not be translated like you use Hardcoded text as the message notify

Comment: But it will give `NPE` if `name` is `NULL`

Comment: check `name` is not `NULL` before using `setText()` function.

Comment: You should not concat a String resource with some value, instead use placeholders in your string resource.

So in your string.xml you do: 

`<string name="string_product_rate_with_ruppe_sign">Something %1$d</string>`

And in your java code you do something like this:

`prodOriginalPriceView.setText(getString(R.string.string_product_rate_with_ruppe_sign), price);`

(you can do the formatting in the xml file: [http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html]

Answer (score 421, accepted):

Resource has the get overloaded version of getString which takes a `varargs` of type `Object`: [getString(int, java.lang.Object...)](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int,%20java.lang.Object...)). If you setup correctly your string in strings.xml, with the correct place holders, you can use this version to retrieve the formatted version of your final String. E.g.

```
<string name="welcome_message">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>
```

using `getString(R.string.welcome_message, "Test", 0);`

android will return a String with

```
 "Hello Test! you have 0 new messages"
```

**About** `setText("" + name);`

Your first Example, `prodNameView.setText("" + name);` doesn't make any sense to me. The TextView is able to handle null values. If name is null, no text will be drawn.

Comment: assuming that on your BigDecimal you will call float value: Add `%1$f` to your string, in strings.xml and then call `setText(getString(R.string.string_product_rate_with_ruppe_sign, new BigDecimal(price).setScale(2, RoundingMode.UP).floatValue() ));`

Comment: it is in the second part of the answer. Have a look

Comment: I want to show a Integer .String stands $s and Decimal $d. So integer stands for ?

Comment: if you mean the "placeholder" you can use `%1$d`. @reegan29

Comment: For anyone looking for the API listing the types of formats: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter#syntax

Comment: Very interesting, I didn't know it

Comment: This answer is very good. If anyone is confused about the %1$s and %2$d, see Rissmon Suresh's answer down below. He explains that part very well.

Answer (score 60):

Don't get confused with   **%1$s** and **%2$d** in the accepted answer.Here is a few extra information.

- The format specifiers can be of the following syntax:

> %[`argument_index`$]`format_specifier`

1. The optional **argument_index** is specified as a number ending with a “$” after the “%” and selects the specified argument in the argument list. The first argument is referenced by **"1$"**, the second by **"2$"**, etc.
2. The required **format specifier** is a character indicating how the argument should be formatted. The set of valid conversions for a given argument depends on the argument's **data type.**

**Example**

We will create the following formatted string where the gray parts are inserted programmatically.

> Hello `Test`! you have `0` new messages

Your `string resource`:

> < string name="welcome_messages">Hello, `%1$s`! You have `%2$d` new
>   messages< /string >

Do the `string substitution` as given below:

> getString(R.string.welcome_message, `"Test"`, `0`);

Note:

- %1$s will be substituted by the string "Test"
- %2$d will be substituted by the string "0"

Answer (score 22):

I ran into the same lint error message and solved it this way.

Initially my code was:

```
private void displayQuantity(int quantity) {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText("" + quantity);
}
```

I got the following error

```
Do not concatenate text displayed with setText. Use resource string with placeholders.
```

So, I added this to `strings.xml`

```
<string name="blank">%d</string>
```

Which is my initial "" + a placeholder for my number(quantity).

**Note**: My `quantity` variable was previously defined and is what I wanted to append to the string.  My code as a result was

```
private void displayQuantity(int quantity) {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText(getString(R.string.blank, quantity));
}
```

After this, my error went away. The behavior in the app did not change and my quantity continued to display as I wanted it to now without a lint error.

Answer (score 19):

Do not concatenate text inside your **setText()** method, Concatenate what ever you want in a **String** and put that String value inside your **setText()** method.

ex: correct way

```
int min = 120;
int sec = 200;
int hrs = 2;

String minutes = String.format("%02d", mins);
String seconds = String.format("%02d", secs);
String newTime = hrs+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;

text.setText(minutes);
```

**Do not** concatenate inside setText() like

```
text.setText(hrs+":"+String.format("%02d", mins)+":"+String.format("%02d", secs));
```

Comment: Why? What advantages does one have other the other?

Comment: This is a cheap cheat. Would be easier to use '@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")'.

Answer (score 11):

You should check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656371/dynamic-string-using-string-xml) and use a placeholder like his one (not tested)

```
<string name="string_product_rate_with_ruppe_sign">Price : %1$d</string>

String text = String.format(getString(R.string.string_product_rate_with_ruppe_sign),new BigDecimal(price).setScale(2, RoundingMode.UP));
prodOriginalPriceView.setText(text);
```

Answer (score 10):

Don't Mad, It's too Simple.

```
String firstname = firstname.getText().toString();
String result = "hi "+ firstname +" Welcome Here";
            mytextview.setText(result);
```

Comment: simple and no warnings

Answer (score 6):

the problem is because you are appending `""` at the beginning of every string.

lint will scan arguments being passed to `setText` and will generate warnings, in your case following warning is relevant:

> Do not build messages by
>   concatenating text chunks. Such messages can not be properly
>   translated.

as you are concatenating every string with `""`.

remove this concatenation as the arguments you are passing are already text. Also, you can use `.toString()` if at all required anywhere else instead of concatenating your string with `""`

Answer (score 6):

I fixed it by using String.format

befor :

```
textViewAddress.setText("Address"+address+"\n"+"nCountry"+"\n"+"City"+"city"+"\n"+"State"+"state")
```

after :

```
textViewAddress.setText(
     String.format("Address:%s\nCountry:%s\nCity:%s\nState:%s", address, country, city, state));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this , it works for me

```
title.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0} {1}", itemList.get(position).getOppName(), itemList.get(position).getBatchNum()));
```

Answer (score 2):

If your case is similar to mine where you don't have access to the resources and you're using Kotlin, you can do this:

```
val v = "hello"

"placeholder $v placeholder".let {
                    textView.text = it
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
prodNameView.setText("" + name); //this produce lint error

val nameStr="" + name;//workaround for quick warning fix require rebuild
prodNameView.setText(nameStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support i18n, you can disable this lint check in Android Studio

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Android -> Lint -> TextView Internationalization(uncheck this)

Comment: Or `@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")` for a less radical approach.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am super late for answering this but I think you can store the data in a varible first then you can provide the variable name. eg:-

```
// Java syntax
    String a = ("" + name);
    String b = "" + String.format(getString(R.string.string_product_rate_with_ruppe_sign);
    String c = "" + new BigDecimal(price).setScale(2, RoundingMode.UP));
    
    prodNameView.setText(a);
    prodOriginalPriceView.setText(b, c);
```

Answer (score 0):

add parentheses to your string

```
time?.text = "time is - ${DYDateUtils.formatDate(lastShowTime)}" //warning

time?.text = ("time is ：${DYDateUtils.formatDate(lastShowTime)}") //no warning
```

Answer (score -1):

if it is textView you can use like that : myTextView.text = ("Hello World")
in editText you can use myTextView.setText("Hello World")