# Concatenate string and integer in string.xml

Tags: android, string, integer, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate string and integer in string.xml like below...

```
<integer name="min_length">10</integer>
<string name="error">Enter minimum @integer/min_length chars</string>
```

So that the value of getString(R.string.error) could be "Enter minimum 10 chars". But getting error, please help!

Comment: I don't think its possible.

Comment: it is not possible. Do it a Runtime ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164886/android-textview-do-not-concatenate-text-displayed-with-settext/33165040#33165040) an  example)

Comment: I know the solution via run time. But I need the way what I mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: Can `strings.xml` even contain `<integer>` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not concatenate strings or integer and strings in xml. You can do refer to another string or integer  in one string or integer tag respectively in xml , but only one.
Like:

```
 <integer name="min_length">10</integer>

<integer name="min">@integer/min_length</integer>
```

You can refer integer inside integer and string inside string .

If you try to do what you mentioned above android studio , you will be thrown away with error.

Answer (score 6):

From the link Shree posted

**XML**

```
<string name="error">Enter minimum %1$d chars</string>
```

**Java**

```
int min_length = 10;
Resources res = getResources();
String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.error), min_length);
```

Answer (score 1):

### **A quick solution for your question!**

**Write your `Integer` and `String` like**

```
<integer name="min_length">10</integer>
<string name="error">Enter minimum min_length chars</string>
```

**And Concat them like**

```
String string = 
getString(R.string.error).replace("min_length",
 String.valueOf(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.min_length)))
```

**In Android you can't concatenate Strings inside xml without any logical codes like you have shown**

[See more at formatting and styling String resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this now using DataBinding.

```
<TextView android:text='@{"Enter minimum " + @string/min_length)}' />
```

Read more about DataBinding [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)