# I Build a Brain Trainer app but Not Showing my TEXTVIEW when i run my app and warning is showing do not concatenate text display with setText

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

[image]

```
sumTextView.setText(Integer.toString(a) + " + " + Integer.toString(b));
```

This Line show warning you see in pic..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android TextView : "Do not concatenate text displayed with setText"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164886/android-textview-do-not-concatenate-text-displayed-with-settext)

Comment: Not understanding the issue, please post the xml file or log file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.format();`

```
sumTextView.setText(String.format("%1$d + %2$d", a, b));
```

With this you can format a string correctly with multiple variables, no matter whether they are strings or integers. This example takes the value of variable `a` and replaces the placeholder `%1$d` with it. Same goes for the other variable.

Answer (score 0):

take an string copy whole line in it, then show string in setText

```
String str = (Integer.toString(a) + " + " + Integer.toString(a));
sumTextView.setText(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** The First String Says that do not concate string with setText property.

```
String txt = String.valueOf(a) + " + " + String.valueOf(b);
sumTextView.setText(str);
```

**2.** Second warning says that your program have possibility to crash or genearte an exception in case if value of a or b is null or not an integer.
So check condition `if(a!=null and b!=null)` then display text in if condition.