# Android xml string how to connect

Tags: android, xml, string

Android xml string item how to connect two item
[image]

Comment: This does not work in android. You would have to load both strings at runtime and concatenate them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656371/dynamic-string-using-string-xml/24903097#24903097

Comment: the "c" value is used in AndroidMinifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

If you have these strings:

```
<string name="a">Hello</string>
<string name="b">World</string>
```

Then in your Activity you would do this:

```
String a = getString(R.string.a);
String b = getString(R.string.b);
String c = a + " " + b;
```

Alternatively, you can add a third string and retrieve it this way:

```
<string name="c">%s %s</string>

String c = getString(R.string.c, a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use string-array

```
<string-array name="c">
        <item> @string/a</item>
        <item> " " </item>
        <item> @string/b</item>
</string-array>
```

an in code

```
String c = Arrays.toString(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.c));
```