# Cannot resolve method android

Tags: java, android

I am getting an error "Cannot resolve method 'maketext (android.content.Context, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int ')". I assume that there is some problem with the altitude part (int). Can someone tell me how to fix this?

```
    @OnClick(R.id.btn_get_last_location)
        public void showLastKnownLocation() {
            if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lat: " + mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()
                + ", Lng: " + mCurrentLocation.getLongitude(), ", Alt: " + mCurrentLocation.getAltitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 
        else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Last known location is not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lat: " + mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()
            + ", Lng: " + mCurrentLocation.getLongitude(), ", Alt: " + mCurrentLocation.getAltitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

with

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lat: " + mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()
            + ", Lng: " + mCurrentLocation.getLongitude() + ", Alt: " + mCurrentLocation.getAltitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Oh that's stupid mistake. Thanks a lot for your help Zunjae:)

Comment: It took me quite some time to find what is the difference. Could you please add some explaination about that there is a missing string concatenation (`+`)?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Lat: " + mCurrentLocation.getLatitude() + ", Lng: " + mCurrentLocation.getLongitude() + ", Alt: " + mCurrentLocation.getAltitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Instead of this

```
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lat: " + mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()
            + ", Lng: " + mCurrentLocation.getLongitude(), ", Alt: " + mCurrentLocation.getAltitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But This is not the best approach,According to the android Documentations use string with place holder.
[String With Place Holders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656371/dynamic-string-using-string-xml)

Comment: Thankyou Scienticious. I modified it. Now I have another error "Cannot resolve symbol R" and "No enum constant com.android.manifmerger.AttributeOperationType.CONTEXT". I tried to clean project --> rebuild, invalidating catches & restarting but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I need to wait for another 4 days to post a question..Ufff:(