# Android kotlin string formats in different orders

Tags: android, kotlin, string-formatting

I have some localized string formats with format arguments in different orders. For example I have the phrase **synced 12 files on 6/29/2018** which is to be displayed to the user. Where the **12** and the **6/29/2018** are just placeholders. So the string in my resources looks like

```
 <string name="n_synced_on_date" formatted="false">"%d files synced on %s"</string>
```

The trouble is some of the translators would like to write it

```
 <string name="n_synced_on_date" formatted="false">"bla %s bla bla bla %d bla"</string>
```

So when I run my code

```
 text = String.format(getString(R.string.n_synced_on_date), numberOfFiles, dateString)
```

It will crash for any language that reverses the format arguments.

I was hoping that I could use Kotlin string templates so my resources could be defined as

```
<string name="n_synced_on_date" formatted="false">"$NUMBER files synced on $DATESTRING"</string>
```

this would allow translators to put the words in any order but according to this link [How to apply template to a string returned from a function](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-to-apply-template-to-a-string-returned-from-a-function/942) this is not possible.

My current lousy approach is to catch the number format exception and try the string format with the arguments reversed. I was hoping to find a nice clean solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656371/dynamic-string-using-string-xml) explain, you can proceed like this giving an index to the arguments:

```
<string name="n_synced_on_date" formatted="false">"%1$d files synced on %2$s"</string>
<string name="n_synced_on_date" formatted="false">"bla %2$s bla bla bla %1$d bla"</string>
```

and then you can run the code like you're already doing :

```
String.format(getString(R.string.n_synced_on_date), numberOfFiles, dateString)
```