# Use Strings with placeholder in XML layout android

Tags: android, string, android-layout, android-xml, android-xml-attribute

I have a string with placeholder e.g

```
<string name="str_1">Hello %s</string>
```

I want to use this in xml layout as android:text="@string/str_1". **Is there any way to use this in xml layout to fill the placeholder**?
Thanks in advance. I already know String.format(str,str...) in java/kotlin but i want to use this in xml layout without data binding.

Comment: use data binding https://medium.com/@ubuntudroid/using-string-placeholders-with-data-binding-394615354464

Comment: Try the below Link will help you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656371/dynamic-string-using-string-xml

Comment: @Rahul.. i donot have data object in xml. I have already gone thru the article. Anyways Thanks for mentioning it .

Comment: @AlokSingh. Question is specific about usage of placeholder string in xml layout.

Comment: @SimpleCoder are you changing any thing from xml, if you are how ?

Comment: You'll need to source the value for `%s` from somewhere, and DataBinding is the most "xml" way I can think of to achieve it.

Comment: android:text= "@{@string/generic_name(user.name)}" don't you think 
android:text= "@{@string/generic_name(`Hello World`)}" or
@{String.format(@string/Hello, ``Hello World``)}
 you can do this data binding `Hello world` is in inside back tick

Comment: @Rahul,PPartisan .. Yeah i understand about data binding.. But I want to know if it is possible or not . Thanks anyways

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like this.
Write your string in your (strings.xml) with declaring a string variable (%1$s) inside it. For decimal, we use (%2$d).

```
<string name="my_string">My string name is %1$s</string>
```

And inside the android code (yourFile.java), use this string where you want it.

```
String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.my_string), stringName);
```

This is not a good answer but it may help you get some idea to get going.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to format your strings directly in your XML. Inside your code you can use both `String.format` and `context.getString()` to get and format your string.

If you want to show something just in the XML and not have it in the final build (only have it in compile time), you can also use `tools:` namespace like following:

```
<TextView 
...

    tools:text="Hello, this is a test"

/>
```

This will only appear in the layout editor and will not have any effect in the APK. It can also be used for other fields too, like `tools:visiblity`.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 ways to do string formatting in a layout expression:

```
android:text="@{String.format(@string/str_1, viewModel.username)}"
```

or

```
android:text="@{@string/str_1(viewModel.username)}"
```

Comment: As supportive information, it requires data binding enabled in gradle and a layout tag as a root tag in the view.xml.