# How to use integer in formatting string resource?

Tags: android

I have this type of string:

```
<string name="temperature">%1$s °C</string>
```

How can i use integer in the place where variable should be instead of string? I've seen docs and found info only about string and double

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40715374/4729721

Comment: To add to the above comment, decimal number identifier that is `d` works well with integers and if you keep your code as is, it will still work because integer will be typecasted to string within the limits of casting ofcourse

Comment: @gtxtreme i have crash when i'm using "d" with integer

Comment: You should wrap it in a try-catch construct to know exactly why this happens but I use it and it works for me normally

Answer (score 0):

use this in your XML file to convert integer into a string:

```
<string name="my_name">Text here num %1$d</string>
```

and then in your java file call the XML string resource like this:

```
getString(R.string.my_name), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.num1)));
```

that way the %d gets replaced by the integer you pass in the getString.

Comment: @Dante313 didn't my solution worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

In Android somehow %1$d designed for Int type. %1$f designed for Double type.