# String resource for href in string resource

Tags: android, android-resources, android-productflavors, android-flavors

I have string resource with href like this:

`<string name="name">Some text <a href="http://SUBDOMAIN.domain.com/">Click here</a>.` (`SUBDOMAIN` here is placeholder to show case)

I generated in `SUBDOMAIN` with product flavors:

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
        resValue "string", "sub_domain", "test."
    }
    ...
}
```

I have it in `gradleResValues`:`<string name="sub_domain" translatable="false">test.</string>`

I can not figure out how to use this `sub_domain` in my resource with `href`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656371/is-it-possible-to-have-placeholders-in-strings-xml-for-runtime-values

Comment: I couldn't make it work inside `"` for `href`. If I escape it there is error:  `Attribute value expected` and if I don't anything in those quotes is treated as string and is not parsed/resolved.