# How can I pass value to a variable from string resources in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I got this variable

```
val questionType = R.string.add
```

Here is from the string resource

```
<string name="add">%d + %d?</string>
```

I want to pass value to %d by using `questionType` in a ViewModel, is it possible to do so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have placeholders in strings.xml for runtime values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656371/is-it-possible-to-have-placeholders-in-strings-xml-for-runtime-values)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

`<string name="welcome_messages">Hello, You haven't been around %1$s hours.</string>`

`val text = res.getString(R.string.welcome_messages, hourCount);`

`someTextview.text = text`